# @Html.Radiobutton generating long id & name

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a view that uses the next Model

```
@model Merak.Models.Product.Options.NumberOfObjectsProductOptionModel
```

And 2 radiobuttons

```
 @Html.RadioButton(Constants.HtmlControlValues.OptionNumberObjectSelect, @Model.OptionOnePrice, true) <br/>
    @Html.RadioButton(Constants.HtmlControlValues.OptionNumberObjectSelect, @Model.OptionTwoPrice)
```

Inside constants.HtmlControlValues.OptionNumberObjectSelect is a string with "groupname" inside.

I would think that the Html control would generate something like:

```
<input id="groupname" name="groupname" type="radio" value="50,00">
```

But instead it generates something like:

```
<input id="NumberOfObjectsProductOptionModel_groupname" name="NumberOfObjectsProductOptionModel.groupname" type="radio" value="50,00">
```

Any idea why this behaviour is happening and what I can do to get the short name/id version?

Comment: The whole point of using the html helpers is to bind to model properties. Generating `<input id="groupname" name="groupname" type="radio" value="50,00">` means you wont bind to your model (the model does not contain a property named `groupname`) so just create the html manually - `<input id="groupname" name="groupname" type="radio" value="@Model.OptionOnePrice">`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the constants.HtmlControlValues.OptionNumberObjectSelect to a variable a then get the value:

```
@model Merak.Models.Product.Options.NumberOfObjectsProductOptionModel
@{
   string myControl = constants.HtmlControlValues.OptionNumberObjectSelect
}
```

And then use it in your control:

```
@Html.RadioButton(@myControl, @Model.OptionOnePrice, true)
```

Comment: this still generates the long id

Comment: I have a small test project and I can not reproduce the behavior you have in your application. Are you sure OptionNumberObjectSelect is returning a string value? In my project I have this `public static string OptionNumberObjectSelect { get { return "groupname"; }  }`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.OptionOnePrice)` and see if that works better. That way it's bound to your model.

Comment: this also ouputs a long id i dont want : id="NumberOfObjectsProductOptionModel_OptionOnePrice"